# Java Eclipse Scanner Date

Tags: java, date-parsing

I'm just making a program for fun.

so in my program, I want to create a start promo function, which when using it we can write the promo date, namely dd/MM/yyyy. but I'm confused, about how to get him to scan.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

private void NewClothPromo() {
        String type;
        Date startpromo;

        do {
            System.out.print("Input Cloth Type [Shirt | Pants] (case sensitive): ");
            type = scan.next();
        }while(type.compareTo("Shirt")!=0&&type.compareTo("Pants")!=0);

        do {
            System.out.print("Input Start Promo Date [dd/MM/yyyy]: ");
            startpromo = ......
        }while(startpromo.equals(DateFormat));
```

```
        do {
            System.out.print("Input Start Promo Date [dd/MM/yyyy]: ");
            startpromo = ......
        }while(startpromo.equals(DateFormat));
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please use the classes from the `java.time` package and its sub-packages! `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` are very old classes with some serious flaws - Also you probably want to iterate `while` the entered value does NOT match the format (despite I would not validate just the format, but prefer to validate the date as a whole {reject dates like Feb. 30th})

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. Always take date type inputs from the user as a `String` and after that convert the same to a `Date` instance. Eg:

```
try{
    System.out.println("Input : ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    //parsing the date in desired format if input pattern is ok then it will parse other wise will throw exception
    startpromo = DateFormat.parse(input);
}catch(ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In `do-while` check whether `startpromo` is null or not.

Example using `while` :

```
while(startpromo==null){
 //taking input and convertion
}
```

### Suggestion

Try to use `java.time` for date-time instances as `util.date` is obsolete.
All concepts for formatting are the same except for using another package.

Here is an example for your case:

```java
LocalDate  date = null;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
while(date==null){
    try{
        System.out.println("Input : ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();

        //parsing the date in desired format if input pattern is ok then it will parse other wise will throw exception
        date = LocalDate.parse(input,formatter);
    }catch(DateTimeParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```